# Populate an array with two sums

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sum

I was hoping someone could enlighten me on how to populate an array based on two different sums.

```
    var startingIncome = 30000;
    var startingIncomeArr = [];

    startingIncomeArr[0] = startingIncome;
    for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {

        if (i <= 45) {
            startingIncome += (startingIncome / 100 * 3);
        }else {
            startingIncome += (((startingIncome / 100) * 3) / 2);
        }
        startingIncomeArr[i] = startingIncome;
    }
```

Basically I want the array to be populated up until the index is 45 using one sum and then change to another sum (dividing it by two) after the index reaches 45.

For some reason the sum never gets divided by two after reaching 45.

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong would be appreciated.

EDIT:

It seems my sum was off, I wasn't dividing the whole sum. Here is the corrected code:

```
    var startingIncome = 30000;
    var startingIncomeArr = [];

    startingIncomeArr[0] = startingIncome;
    for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {

        if (i <= 45) {
            startingIncome += (startingIncome / 100 * 3);
        }else {
            startingIncome += (startingIncome / 100 * 3);
            startingIncome /= 2;
        }
        startingIncomeArr[i] = startingIncome;
    }
    console.log(startingIncomeArr);
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen?  You're adding 3% of the value up to 45, and then you want to add 1.5%; at least, that's what your code does now.  The sum never gets divided by two because your code doesn't do that.

Comment: With your code now, entry 45 is 113447.87524954027 and entry 46 is 115149.59337828337.  What should entry 46 be if not that value?

Comment: Maybe you should make your requirement more clear, based on your interpretation, your implementations makes sense. At least, technically it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it as two sequential loops:

```
var startingIncome = 30000;
var startingIncomeArr = [];
var i;

startingIncomeArr[0] = startingIncome;
for (i = 1; i <= 45; i++) {
    startingIncome += (startingIncome / 100 * 3);
    startingIncomeArr[i] = startingIncome;
}
for (i = 46; i < 100; i++) {
    startingIncome += (((startingIncome / 100) * 3) / 2);
    startingIncomeArr[i] = startingIncome;
}
```

That way it's clear from the `for` statements themselves that the logic covers two different ranges. You also avoid an `if` evaluation each time through the loop.

Comment: Thanks @Ted but I managed to fixed my incorrect sum to solve the issue.